# How to List the Set of In-links to a Node

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Suppose I have the edges set below. From this, can a list of all nodes that in-link to all other nodes be generated? For example, 17 nodes link into node 5 (i.e., 17 nodes point to node 5 as a directed link) and these are the set `{27,23,22,21,4,25,7,24,30,15,18,19,29,3,8,9,10}`. How can I generate a set like this (a set of inlinks) for all nodes in the graph?

```
edges = {5 -> 27, 27 -> 5, 5 -> 23, 23 -> 5, 27 -> 23, 23 -> 27,     5
-> 22, 22 -> 5, 27 -> 22, 22 -> 27, 5 -> 21, 21 -> 5, 27 -> 21,     21 -> 27, 5 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 27 -> 4, 4 -> 27, 5 -> 25, 25 -> 5,     27 -> 25, 25 -> 27, 5 -> 7, 7 -> 5, 5 -> 24, 24 -> 5, 27 -> 26,     26 ->
 27, 27 -> 24, 24 -> 27, 24 -> 20, 5 -> 30, 30 -> 5, 15 -> 5,     5 ->
 18, 18 -> 5, 5 -> 19, 19 -> 5, 15 -> 18, 18 -> 15, 18 -> 19,     19 ->
 18, 29 -> 5, 5 -> 29, 29 -> 27, 27 -> 29, 29 -> 1, 1 -> 29,     29 ->
 18, 18 -> 29, 29 -> 15, 15 -> 29, 28 -> 29, 29 -> 30,     30 -> 29, 5
 -> 11, 18 -> 16, 16 -> 18, 18 -> 17, 56 -> 18,     15 -> 12, 12 -> 15, 15 -> 13, 13 -> 15, 15 -> 14, 14 -> 15, 5 -> 3,
     3 -> 5, 5 -> 8, 8 -> 5, 5 -> 9, 9 -> 5, 5 -> 10, 10 -> 5, 5 -> 31,
     27 -> 31, 5 -> 32, 27 -> 32, 5 -> 33, 27 -> 33, 5 -> 34, 27 -> 34,
     5 -> 35, 27 -> 35, 5 -> 36, 27 -> 36, 5 -> 37, 27 -> 37, 5 -> 38,     27 -> 38, 5 -> 39, 27 -> 39, 5 -> 40, 27 -> 40, 21 -> 41, 42 -> 9,    
 1 -> 6, 6 -> 1};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple pattern matching:

```
Cases[edges, edge : (v_ -> 5) :> v]
```

> `{27, 23, 22, 21, 4, 25, 7, 24, 30, 15, 18, 19, 29, 3, 8, 9, 10}`

If you had specified the graph using `DirectedEdge` instead, then the pattern would have looked like this:

```
Cases[DirectedEdge @@@ edges, edge : DirectedEdge[v_, 5] :> v]
```

> `{27, 23, 22, 21, 4, 25, 7, 24, 30, 15, 18, 19, 29, 3, 8, 9, 10}`

If you have a big graph, `IncidenceList` can be used to efficiently narrow it down to all edges that are incident to a given node:

```
Cases[
 IncidenceList[Graph[edges], 5],
 DirectedEdge[v_, 5] :> v
 ]
```

> `{27, 23, 22, 21, 4, 25, 7, 24, 30, 15, 18, 19, 29, 3, 8, 9, 10}`

This leverages the graph functions even more:

```
g = Graph[edges];
m = IncidenceMatrix[g];
First /@ Extract[
  EdgeList[g],
  Position[m[[VertexIndex[g, 5], ;;]] // Normal, 1]
  ]
```

> `{27, 23, 22, 21, 4, 25, 7, 24, 30, 15, 18, 19, 29, 3, 8, 9, 10}`

Comment: many thanks all ... very efficient and creative ... prg

Answer (score 4):

A few additional alternatives:

#### [`VertexInComponent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexInComponent.html)

```
Rest @ VertexInComponent[edges, 5,1]
```

> {27, 23, 22, 21, 4, 25, 7, 24, 30, 15, 18, 19, 29, 3, 8, 9, 10}

#### [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html)

```
GroupBy[edges, Last -> First] @ 5
```

> {27, 23, 22, 21, 4, 25, 7, 24, 30, 15, 18, 19, 29, 3, 8, 9, 10}

#### [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
Rest @ DeleteDuplicates[5 /. List /@ Reverse /@ edges]
```

> {27, 23, 22, 21, 4, 25, 7, 24, 30, 15, 18, 19, 29, 3, 8, 9, 10}

#### [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) + "AdjacencyLists"

```
SparseArray[Reverse /@ List @@@ edges -> 1]["AdjacencyLists"][[5]]
```

> {27, 23, 22, 21, 4, 25, 7, 24, 30, 15, 18, 19, 29, 3, 8, 9, 10}

```
Transpose[SparseArray[List @@@ edges -> 1]]["AdjacencyLists"][[5]]
```

> {3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27, 29, 30}

Comment: Ah, there it is! I was almost sure there should be a function like that (`VertexInComponent`), I just couldn't find it. It's not linked from related functions like `VertexInDegree`. +1